# How to create array of objects from keys and values of another object

Tags: javascript, arrays, javascript-objects

I've got an object:

```
const costCentres = {
    "11738838-bf34-11e9-9c1c-063863da20d0": "Refit 2018",
    "f30d72f4-a16a-11e9-9c1c-063863da20d0": "Refit 2019",
    "f7fa34ed-a16a-11e9-9c1c-063863da20d0": "Refit 2020"
  };
```

What I need is an array of object like this:

```
[
    {
        id: "11738838-bf34-11e9-9c1c-063863da20d0",
        type: "Cost Centre",
        name: "Refit 2018",
        chosen: false
    },
    {
        id: "f30d72f4-a16a-11e9-9c1c-063863da20d0",
        type: "Cost Centre",
        name: "Refit 2019",
        chosen: false
    },
    {
        id: "f7fa34ed-a16a-11e9-9c1c-063863da20d0",
        type: "Cost Centre",
        name: "Refit 2020",
        chosen: false
    }
]
```

This is my solution so far:

```
let centresToEntities = []

    for (const key in costCentres) {
      centresToEntities.push({
        id: key,
        type: 'Cost Centre',
        name: costCentres[key],
        chosen: false
      });
    }
```

It is working but I don't want to use for in loop.
What would be the other way to do it?

Comment: Why don't you want to use a for in loop? You are going to be using some sort of loop anyway.

Comment: for the compiler warning "for..in loops iterate over the entire prototype chain, which is virtually never what you want."

Comment: Was thinking about switching it off but prefer to go with Object.entries(costCentres).map from Barmar's below example

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `Object.entries()` and `.map()`

```js
const costCentres = {
  "11738838-bf34-11e9-9c1c-063863da20d0": "Refit 2018",
  "f30d72f4-a16a-11e9-9c1c-063863da20d0": "Refit 2019",
  "f7fa34ed-a16a-11e9-9c1c-063863da20d0": "Refit 2020"
};

let centresToEntities = Object.entries(costCentres).map(([key, value]) => ({
  id: key,
  type: 'Cost Centre',
  name: value,
  chosen: false
}));

console.log(centresToEntities);
```

Comment: Nice done @Barmar

Answer (score 1):

A slight tweak to @Barmar's perfect solution:

```js
const 
      costCentres = {
          "11738838-bf34-11e9-9c1c-063863da20d0": "Refit 2018",
          "f30d72f4-a16a-11e9-9c1c-063863da20d0": "Refit 2019",
          "f7fa34ed-a16a-11e9-9c1c-063863da20d0": "Refit 2020"
      },
      
      type = 'Cost Center',
      chosen = false,
      
      centresToEntities = Object.entries(costCentres).map(
          ([id, name]) => ({id, type, name, chosen})
      );
      
console.log( centresToEntities );
```